# Outlook VBA code to insert time created into email subject bar

Tags: vba, date, time, outlook

I'm fairly new to VBA code and have an issue I can't solve.  Currently I have taken a VBA script from the internet as seen below:

```
Public Sub Whatever(Mail As Outlook.MailItem)
Mail.Subject = Mail.Subject & " " & Mail.CreationTime
Mail.Save
End Sub
```

I then applied this to my inbox using a rule so that it would take the subject and insert the time and date the email was created behind it.  The rule looked like so :

Apply to message

on this computer only

run "Project1.Whatever"

This worked great last week but when I tried to use it today it has stopped.  Any suggestions as to why this is or whether there is a better way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> This worked great last week but when I tried to use it today it has stopped.

Why do you need to create a rule if you run it manually each time?

Instead, you can develop a VBA macro which can handle the [Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event.startup.aspx) or [MAPILogonComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event.mapilogoncomplete.aspx) events of the Application class and process all items programmatically. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.